# Async challenge when looping over urls in nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, electron, nightmare

I'm using the async module to iterate over multiple urls with nightmarejs. I can't create a new nightmare instance because I will have to reauthenticate each time.

So I'm trying to use the async module. I'm getting a (I think, classic) problem the url for all iterations being the final url in the array - not each individual url. I thought using the async module would fix this (I also tried using let) but I'm still getting the problem

```
'use strict'

var Nightmare = require("nightmare");
var async = require("async");

//Creates the authenticated nightmare instance

var scraper = new Nightmare()
  .goto('https://www.example.com/signin')
  .type('#login', 'username')
  .type('#password', 'password')
  .click('#btn')
  .run(function(err, nightmare) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Done.');
  });

//Trying to use async module to iterate through urls

function load(url, callback){
  scraper
  .goto(url)
  .wait(2000)
  .screenshot('pic'+url[25]+'.png')
  .run(function(err, nightmare) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Done with ', url[25]);
    callback()
  }); 
}

var urls = [
  'https://www.example.com/p1',
  'https://www.example.com/p2',
  'https://www.example.com/p3',
]

async.each(urls, load, function (err) {
  console.log('done!');
});
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lay with this line:

```
async.each(urls, load, function (err) {
```

By default, `async` runs `each` in parallel ([see the documentation here](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback), if you're curious).  Nightmare is not capable of executing multiple requests in parallel, and as such, doing so will result in errant results like what you're seeing.

The solution is straightforward: switch to using `async.eachSeries`.  That will guarantee your requests will be run in series, allowing Nightmare to work as designed.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense!